# Angular Best Practice for ag-Grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid

My angular app have 2 controllers. My problem is that the controllers does not keep the data when the user navigates away from the page.

In the first controller i have an ag-Grid configured for the infinity scroll

In the second controller i have the detail

If the user scroll to 307° record,
then click to view the detail
when return to ag-grid, this shows the first 100 records

How can I configure the grid to start viewing from the 307th record?

Comment: are you using routing to navigate through the components? or you have [lazy-loading material tabs](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#lazy-loading) kinda sutuation? the solution depends on the approach you are using. If you describe it through some live example, you would get perfect approach for it.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you need to track the last position which was requested via scrolling and then keep that value on `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`, and on init phase - check this value and request needed amount of data from server till needed **page**.

Not sure about *automated* proceed but here is a sample for **save\restore** states via buttons

Check [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-infinite-scrolling/#example-using-cache-api-methods) about API for infinite scroll

```
private endRow: Number;

save(){
    localStorage.setItem('endRow', this.endRow);
}

restore(){
    let restoredValue= Number(localStorage.getItem('endRow'));
    if(restoredValue)
        this.gridApi.ensureIndexVisible(restoredValue);
  }
}
...
var dataSource = {
    rowCount: null,
    getRows: (params)=> {
        this.endRow = params.endRow;   <--- track end row
        ....
```

[Plnkr sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/VI7hEN?p=preview)